# calling function within module that is imported to another class

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript (working my way through some basic tutorials). Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here? I am trying to get the `run` function to reference the `withinCircle` function, then export the whole thing to another file so I can reference the `run` function. Feel free to modify my code anyway you want- I tried to follow "best" practices but I may have screwed up. Thanks!

```
var roleGuard = {

    /** @param {Creep} creep **/
    run: function(creep) 
    {
        var target = creep.pos.findClosestByRange(FIND_HOSTILE_CREEPS, {filter: { owner: { username: 'Invader' } }});
        if(target!=null)
        {
            console.log(new RoomPosition(target.pos.x,target.pos.y,'sim'));
            //ranged attack here
            //within 3, but further than 1
            if(creep.pos.getRangeTo(target)<=3&&creep.pos.getRangeTo(target)>1) 
            {
                creep.rangedAttack(target);
                console.log("ranged attacking");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var pp=withinCircle(creep,target,3,'sim');
            console.log(pp);
            creep.moveTo(pp);
        }
    }
//------------------------------------------------------------
//move to closest point within z units of given evenmy
    withinCircle: function(creep,target,z,room)
    {
        var targets = [new RoomPosition(target.pos.x-z,target.pos.y-z,room), new RoomPosition(target.pos.x+z,target.pos.y-z,room),new RoomPosition(target.pos.x-z,target.pos.y+z,room),new RoomPosition(target.pos.x+z,target.pos.y+z,room)];
        var closest = creep.pos.findClosestByRange(targets);
        return(closest);
    }
//------------------------------------------------------------
};
module.exports = roleGuard;
```

Other file contains:

```
var roleGuard = require('role.guard');
```

Comment: run and withinCircle are part of the same object, I think all you need to do is call the function using `this` so `var pp=this.withinCircle(...);`

Answer (score 0):

for example:

```
// foo.js
function add(a,b){
  return a + b
}

module.exports = add
```

and in the other file:

```
// bar.js
const add = require("./foo");

console.log(add(1,1))
```

those paths are relative to the file location. extension can be omitted.

you'll need [node](https://nodejs.org/en/) or [browserify](http://browserify.org/) or [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) to make exports/require to work properly.

if you want a better explanation about modular javascript, [look there](https://github.com/substack/browserify-handbook), even if you not enter in the browserify world it will present you to what we can do nowadays.

**EDIT:**

in order to export more symbols you can do the following:

```
// foo2.js
function add(a,b){
  return a + b
}

function multiply(a,b){
  return a * b
}

module.exports = {
  add:add,
  multiply:multiply
}
```

And then in the consumer:

```
// bar2.js
const add      = require("./foo2").add
const multiply = require("./foo2").multiply
//...
```

This is also valid:

```
// foo3.js
function add(a,b){
  return a + b
}
exports.add = add

function multiply(a,b){
  return a * b
}
exports.multiply = multiply
```

Consumer will need no relevant alteration:

```
// bar3.js
const add      = require("./foo3").add
const multiply = require("./foo3").multiply
//...
```

If using [babel](https://babeljs.io/)/es6 modules have a different idion, which you can check [there](http://es6-features.org/#ValueExportImport).

Comment: Hi, indeed it was lacking information, @Rilcon42, hope it helps now